How to use OpenTelemetry Collector to query multiple databases as a metric
I'm currently using the sqlquery receiver of the OpenTelemetry Collector to query a single database for custom metrics. Now, I need to expand this query to cover multiple data sources. With 20 databases to query, copying and pasting the same query and metric configurations results in about 2000 lines of code, which is unreadable, unmaintainable, and prone to errors.
Does anyone have suggestions or best practices for efficiently managing queries across multiple databases?

I tried making a script to generate the datasources config without manually copying and pasting which but lead to a file with 2000 lines which is a bad idea
I tried expanding with helm template, to generate the receivers config with _helpers.tpl, but overriding the default otel config map is not recommended

